# ASP.NET MVC 4 список пользователей онлайн

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Использую в проекте на MVC 4 стандартную авторизацию пользователей SimpleMembership.

Необходимо получить список тех пользователей, которые в данный момент онлайн, то есть на сайте. Подскажите, есть ли для этого стандартные средства в SimpleMembership? Возможно, у кого-то найдется пример (я не нашел).

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [GetNumberOfUsersOnline класса Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline(v=vs.110).aspx).